# Variable is suddenly switching to undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I marked the third console.log - "console.log(elements[i])".  At that point, elements[i] is undefined, but before then it behaves as expected.  Any ideas how/why this is happening?

```
function get_all_tasks_within_div(div_id) {
  var options = []
  var checked_options = []
  var elements = document.getElementById(div_id).querySelectorAll('*');
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].getAttribute("name") == "task") {
      options.push(elements[i].value)
      if (elements[i].checked == true) {
        checked_options.push(elements[i].value)
      }
    }
  }
  return [options, checked_options]
}

function create_exhibits_list(deliverable_id) {
  exhibits[deliverable_id] = []
  var elements = document.getElementsByName("exhibit")
  //get all exibits and sort
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    try {
      console.log(elements[i])
      var element_id = elements[i].id;
      var exhibit_number = document.getElementById(element_id + "exhibit_number").value;
      var exhibit_name = document.getElementById(element_id + "exhibit_name").value;
      var responsible_party = document.getElementById(element_id + "responsible_party").value;
      var deliverable_type = document.getElementById(element_id + "type").value;
      var deliverable_type_options = Array.apply(null, document.getElementById(element_id + "type").options).map(function(el) {
        return el.value;
      });
      var responsible_party_options = Array.apply(null, document.getElementById(element_id + "responsible_party").options).map(function(el) {
        return el.value;
      });
      console.log(elements[i])
      var task_data = get_all_tasks_within_div(element_id + "tasks");

      console.log(elements[i]) // *****

      var task_options = task_data[0]
      var task_checked_options = task_data[1]
      exhibits[deliverable_id].push({
        'exhibit_number': exhibit_number,
        'exhibit_name': exhibit_name,
        'responsible_party': responsible_party,
        'deliverable_type': deliverable_type,
        'deliverable_type_options': deliverable_type_options,
        'responsible_party_options': responsible_party_options,
        'task_options': task_options,
        'task_checked_options': task_checked_options,
        'exhibit_id': element_id,
        'exhibit_int': parseInt(element_id.replace(deliverable_id + "exhibit", ""), 10)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

Comment: `getElmentsByName` returns a live collection. Are you making any modifications to the DOM?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that goes with this code?

Comment: I don't think so.  While the function is running, which should only take a few milliseconds, nothing should change in the DOM.

Comment: in the line that makes the crash you calling a second function that again declares variables { i , elements }. try to change them to { j , insideElements }, maybe it is just that

Comment: Yeah, your `i` counter is *global*. while the `for` loop is running, you're calling another function that uses the same global `i` and thus increments it. After that function runs, the `i` will have the value leftover from the loop inside `get_all_tasks_within_div`. Declare the variable properly instead of having it as an implicit global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the global variable `i` in both functions, so the `for` loop in `get_all_tasks_within_div()` changes the variable `i` in `create_exhibits_list()`. So when you use `elements[i]` after calling the function, `i` has changed to a nonexistent index in the `elements` array.

You should always declare variables to be local with `var` or `let` unless you specifically need to use a global variable.

Comment: "*unless you specifically need to use a global variable.*" which would ideally be as close as possible as "never". In fact, I'd suggest you *always* use a linter and *always* enable the rule to make it an error to refer to a global variable without specifying `window`. This prevents so many errors.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  New to javascript.  This global v. local thing, along with how careful you have to be with it can really cause chaos.  Thank you very much!